# 'list' object is not callable, no entiendo en que estoy fallando, creo que el problema esta en la funcion, pero no se como resolverlo

Tags: python, funciones

Creo que lo que esta mal es la parte de las funciones, que a la hora de llamar la funcion "criterio_victoria" me arroja error en la linea 30, tambien me arroja un error en la linea 19, si alguien me pudiera ayudar me seria de mucha ayuda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    import random
base_de_datos = ['rango','camas', 'marzo', 'licra','zarco', 'cinta', 'micro', 'antro', 'largo','ricos','metro', 'retos', 'hueco','cerca']
seleccion=random.choice(base_de_datos)
palabra = [i for i in seleccion]

def criterio_victoria(entrada):
    if entrada == palabra:
        print("felicitaciones, adivinaste la palabra")
        print()
        return True
    elif entrada!= palabra:
        respuesta_intento=[]
        for i in entrada:
            if i != palabra[entrada.index(i)] and (i not in palabra):
                respuesta_intento.append("-"+i)
            elif i == palabra[entrada.index(i)]:
                respuesta_intento.appened("+"+i)
            elif (palabra.index(i)) != entrada.index(i) and (i in palabra):
                respuesta_intento("*"+i)
    print(" ".join(respuesta_intento))
    print()
    return False
intentos=6
while intentos > 0:
    entrada_I = str(input("Adivine la palabra de 5 caracteres (en minusculas): "))
    print()
    print("tenga en cuenta que: -(letra): la letra no pertenece a la palabra"+"\n"+"+(letra): la letra pertenece y esta en la posicion correcta"+"\n"+"*(letra): la letra pertenece a la palabra, pero no esta en la posicion correcta")
    print()
    entrada =[i for i in entrada_I]
    decision =criterio_victoria(entrada)
    if decision == True:
        break
    print("Tienes"+ intentos-1+ "intento(s) restante(s)")
    print()
    intentos-=1
    if intentos==0:
        print("Lo siento, has perdido. La respuesta correcta era: "+ seleccion)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

La variable `respuesta_intento` es una lista. Al escribir

```
                respuesta_intento("*"+i)
```

estas considerando `respuesta_intento` como una función ... na'que ver. Probablemente quisiste decir

```
respuesta_intento.append("*"+i)
```

Otro error:

```
respuesta_intento.appened("+"+i)
```

escribistes mal `append`.

Answer (score 1):

```
respuesta_intento.appened("+"+i)
```

esa linea de codigo esta mal escrita, es append...

ademas, estsa considerando respuesta_intento como una function, por lo cual si quieres agregar datos, deberias usar esto

```
respuesta_intento.append("*"+i)
```